# Add button with image to UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uisearchbar

I use custom UISearchBar and I override function "draw":

```
class MySearchBar: UISearchBar {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let index = indexOfSearchFieldInSubviews() {
            self.showsCancelButton = false
            searchField.clearButtonMode = .never
        }
    }

    func indexOfSearchFieldInSubviews() -> Int! {        
        var index: Int!
        let searchBarView = subviews[0]        
        for i in 0 ..< searchBarView.subviews.count {
            if searchBarView.subviews[i].isKind(of: UITextField.self) {
                index = i
                break
            }
        }

        return index
    }
}
```

How can I add this button with red image inside UISearchBar?

[image: custom UISearchBar]

Comment: What does your custom drawing code do? You can set an image for the button there by calling `setImage(someImage, for: .bookmark, state: .normal)`

Comment: Yes, but how can I add button inside MySearchBar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add this code inside function **draw(_ rect: CGRect)**:

```
let img = UIImage(named: "openFullList")
let imageButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
imageButton.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width - (img?.size.width)!, y: (self.frame.height - (img?.size.height)!)/2.0, width: (img?.size.width)!, height: (img?.size.height)!)
imageButton.setImage(img, for:UIControlState.normal)
self.addSubview(imageButton)
```

Answer (score 7):

A `UISearchBar` is just a subclass of `UIView`. I suppose you could add a `UIButton` as you would any other view.

However, there is already a button at the location you want to add your button. `UISearchBar` comes with a bookmarks button that you can set a custom image on (by calling `setImage(someImage, for: .bookmark, state: .normal)`). This button has a `UISearchBarDelegate` method from which you can respond to touch-up-inside events.

```
func searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    print("The button on the right side of my search bar was pressed")
}
```

I find this approach clearer than trying to guess the appropriate size and placement for a custom button, the "bookmark" misnomer not withstanding.

I would also recommend not overriding `draw(_ rect:)` for initialization and property setting. There is a performance cost to overriding it, and only custom drawing code needs to be there.

Comment: Great answer but how do I change the accessibility of the bookmark Icon?

Comment: to add accessibility use just do: img?.accessibilityLabel = "..."

Comment: This bookmark button disappears when textfield is active and editing. How can we make it stay on searchBar always?

Comment: Found a solution: searchController.searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = true
Make sure this is not made false anywhere in the code or in the updateSearchResults function.